# How to save very large ndarray to disk?

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, multidimensional-array

How to save very large ndarray to disk?

Please note, that any solution, including duplicating of data is not acceptable.

For example, this code

```
x = pandas.HDFStore("some_file.hdf")
x.append("a", pandas.DataFrame(a))
```

includes

```
pandas.DataFrame(a)
```

which unapprovable duplicates memory usage.

Obvious code

```
pickle.dump(a, f)
```

hangs.

Comment: Have you looked into some alternatives to `pickle`? Some ideas here: http://www.benfrederickson.com/dont-pickle-your-data/

Comment: I tried cPickle and found it has unbreakable limit of 4GB. Also looked at MessagePack, but haven't understood how to serialize data with it. Didnt try JSON, because thought that writing as text can't be effective.

Comment: Can `np.save` handle it?  If not, how much data is it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like numpy's save function can handle large arrays.

```
from pylab import *
q = randn(1000, 1000, 1000)
print('{} G'.format(q.nbytes/1024**3))
np.save(open('test_large_array_save.dat', 'wb'), q, allow_pickle=False)
```

Result

```
7.450580596923828 G
```

and a 7.5 G file created on disk.

Monitoring python's memory usage shows that it doesn't increases notably during the save, so a copy isn't being created.

Comment: plus, some discussion on it: http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Huge-arrays-td25254.html

Comment: If you're asking about the format used, the docs have some details: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html